# All the System Root certificates are untrusted in Mavericks

Tags: mac, certificate, osx-mavericks, root

I have a **OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks)** in which all the **certificates** in **System Root** are being shown as **un-trusted.**

[List of all available trusted certificates in OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202858)

Due to this I cannot open websites or appstore. Network connectivity is Good though. It pings websites and i can connect to it remotely as well

**What I have checked :**

1. I have made sure that Data & Time settings are correct.
2. Repaired disk permissions
3. Create new user account
4. Repair & reset KeyChain which has no effect as it only changes login.keychain not system keychain
5. Ensured that all the other machines, imaged the same way does not have this issue
6. Certificates have default setting and have been played with

**I am looking for a way to resolve this without having to re-install OS. There must be a way to resolve this without having to trust each and every one of them manually.**

Comment: [Export](http://support.citrix.com/article/ctx108800) the certificates from a working installation of OS X then import them on the non-working installation.  You basically want to replace the [keychain](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52654/how-to-delete-or-untrust-all-root-certificates-in-osx) since its clearly been compromised.  I suggest you use the built-in tools to fix the problem though, if you do that, backup your personal data first.

Comment: actually, i did try importing the certificate from a working computer but the system would not let me import it to system root(it was unlocked). I have already tried using keychain first aid and resetting it. Security utility that you are referring to, is just another way to delete certificates from system root manually. One by one

Comment: Re-installing the OS was way too much work for the user so I convinced myself to sit down & trust all the certificates manually. 

Trusted Apple root CA & Apple root certificate Authority and all the other certificates show trusted now. Weird :-x

Answer (score 0):

On 10.11.5 i have the same prodlem.
And I make Apple Root CA as Always TRUSTED and then make in "System Defaults" . All another certificates now marked as trusted

Comment: Yes that's what happened with me too